# replace commas with point and convert values in floats (python dictionary)

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to convert some values (read as strings) in a python dictionary.

Suppose this is my starting dictionary:

```
dd = {'sp': ['1,1', '3,2'], 'tt': ['a', 'b'], 'zz': [4.5, 2.1]}
```

what I would like to do is run a test on the dictionary values and if there is a comma (`,`) replace it with a point (`.`) and convert it in a float.

In other words, dd should be transformed into this new dictionary:

```
dd = {'sp': [1.1, 3.2], 'tt': ['a', 'b'], 'zz': [4.5, 2.1]}
```

I thought this as a starting point:

```
for i, v in enumerate(d.values()):
    if ',' in v[i] and isinstance(v[i], str):
        float(v[i].replace(',', '.'))
```

but values are not *overwritten* in the original dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate over each `item` in each dictionary value and convert it to a `float` in the case where the `item` is both of type `str` and contains a `,`:

```
dd = {'sp': ['1,1', '3,2'], 'tt': ['a', 'b'], 'zz': [4.5, 2.1]}

for k in dd:
    dd[k] = [float(item.replace(',', '.')) if type(item) == str and ',' in item
        else item for item in dd[k]]

print(dd)
```

**Output**

```
{'tt': ['a', 'b'], 'sp': [1.1, 3.2], 'zz': [4.5, 2.1]}
```

You need to check that the `item` is of type `str` because checking for the existence of a string (eg `,`) in a `float` will generate a `TypeError`.

if you wanted to do the same thing, but without using a list comprehension (see the comments), you could do the following:

```
dd = {'sp': ['1,1', '3,2'], 'tt': ['a', 'b'], 'zz': [4.5, 2.1]}

for k in dd:
    for i in range(len(dd[k])):
        if type(dd[k][i]) == str and ',' in dd[k][i]:
            dd[k][i] = float(dd[k][i].replace(',', '.'))

print(dd)
```

Comment: less than 5 minutes.. awesome.. just one more thing.. is it possible to write your code without list comprehension?

Comment: @matteo please see my updated answer for this functionality